# Solidity Error : gas required exceeds allowance (25000000)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

Im struggling with some solidity error that makes no sense to me, when calling the distribute function of this contract :

```
contract RewardsContract is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
   
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal = 30000 * 10**18;
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;

    string private _name = "RewardsContract";
    string private _symbol = "RewardsContract";
    uint8 private _decimals = 18;
    
    uint256 public _taxFee = 2;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    
    uint256 public _liquidityFee = 18; //(2% liquidityAddition + 1% rewardsDistribution + 1% devExpenses)
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
    
    address [] public tokenHolder;
    uint256 public numberOfTokenHolders = 0;
    mapping(address => bool) public exist;
    uint256 public ethFees;

    //No limit
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = _tTotal;
    address payable wallet;
    IPancakeRouter02 public immutable pancakeRouter;
    address public immutable pancakePair;
    
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = false;
    uint256 private minTokensBeforeSwap = 8;
    
    event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );
    
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }
    
    constructor () public {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        wallet = msg.sender;
        IPancakeRouter02 _pancakeRouter = IPancakeRouter02(0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1);
         // Create a pancake pair for this new token
        pancakePair = IPancakeFactory(_pancakeRouter.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _pancakeRouter.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        pancakeRouter = _pancakeRouter;
        
        //exclude owner and this contract from fee
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function isExcludedFromReward(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _isExcluded[account];
    }

    function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }

    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }

    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner() {
        // require(account != 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D, 'We can not exclude pancake router.');
        require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
            _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
        }
        _isExcluded[account] = true;
        _excluded.push(account);
    }

    function includeInReward(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                _tOwned[account] = 0;
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    bool public limit = true;
    function changeLimit() public onlyOwner(){
        require(limit == true, 'limit is already false');
            limit = false;
    }
    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        if(limit ==  true && from != owner() && to != owner()){
            if(to != pancakePair){
                require(((balanceOf(to).add(amount)) <= 500 ether));
            }
            require(amount <= 100 ether, 'Transfer amount must be less than 100 tokens');
            }
        if(from != owner() && to != owner())
            require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");

        // is the token balance of this contract address over the min number of
        // tokens that we need to initiate a swap + liquidity lock?
        // also, don't get caught in a circular liquidity event.
        // also, don't swap & liquify if sender is pancake pair.
        if(!exist[to]){
            tokenHolder.push(to);
            numberOfTokenHolders++;
            exist[to] = true;
        }
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= minTokensBeforeSwap;
        if (
            overMinTokenBalance &&
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            from != pancakePair &&
            swapAndLiquifyEnabled
        ) {
            //add liquidity
            swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
        }
        
        //indicates if fee should be deducted from transfer
        bool takeFee = true;
        
        //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
            takeFee = false;
        }
        
        //transfer amount, it will take tax, burn, liquidity fee
        _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
    }
    mapping(address => uint256) public myRewards;
    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        uint256 forLiquidity = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
        uint256 devExp = contractTokenBalance.div(4);
        uint256 forRewards = contractTokenBalance.div(4);
        // split the liquidity
        uint256 half = forLiquidity.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = forLiquidity.sub(half);
        // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
        // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
        // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
        // has been manually sent to the contract
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

        // swap tokens for ETH
        swapTokensForEth(half.add(devExp).add(forRewards)); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

        // how much ETH did we just swap into?
        uint256 Balance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);
        uint256 oneThird = Balance.div(3);
        ethFees = ethFees.add(oneThird);
        wallet.transfer(oneThird);

       // for(uint256 i = 0; i < numberOfTokenHolders; i++){
         //   uint256 share = (balanceOf(tokenHolder[i]).mul(ethFees)).div(totalSupply());
           // myRewards[tokenHolder[i]] = myRewards[tokenHolder[i]].add(share);
        //}
        // add liquidity to pancake
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, oneThird);
        
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, oneThird, otherHalf);
    }
    function seeRewards() public view returns(uint256){
        address sender = msg.sender;
        return myRewards[sender];
    }
    function getRewards() public returns(bool){
        require(myRewards[msg.sender] > 0, 'You have zero rewards right now');
        uint256 _rewards = myRewards[msg.sender];
        myRewards[msg.sender] = myRewards[msg.sender].sub(_rewards);
        msg.sender.transfer(_rewards);
        return true;
    }

    function distribute() public returns(bool){
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < numberOfTokenHolders; i++){
            if(tokenHolder[i] != pancakePair && !_isExcluded[tokenHolder[i]]){
            uint256 share = (balanceOf(tokenHolder[i]).mul(ethFees)).div(totalSupply()-(balanceOf(pancakePair)));
            myRewards[tokenHolder[i]] = myRewards[tokenHolder[i]].add(share);
        }
        }
        ethFees = 0;
    }
    
    function expectedRewards(address sender) public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 _share = (balanceOf(sender).mul(ethFees)).div(totalSupply()-(balanceOf(pancakePair)));
        return _share;
    }
    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the pancake pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = pancakeRouter.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(pancakeRouter), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        pancakeRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(pancakeRouter), tokenAmount);

        // add the liquidity
        pancakeRouter.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    //this method is responsible for taking all fee, if takeFee is true
    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {
        if(!takeFee)
            removeAllFee();
        
        if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
        
        if(!takeFee)
            restoreAllFee();
    }

    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);           
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);   
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);        
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, _getRate());
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }
    
    function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
        if(_isExcluded[address(this)])
            _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
    }
    
    function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }
    
    function removeAllFee() private {
        if(_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0) return;
        
        _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        
        _taxFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
    }
    
    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
        _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
    }
    
    function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
    }
    
    function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
    }
    
    function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
    }
    
    function setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner() {
         require(taxFee <= 10, "Maximum tax limit is 10 percent");
        _taxFee = taxFee;
    }
    
    function setLiquidityFeePercent(uint256 liquidityFee) external onlyOwner() {
        require(liquidityFee <= 10, "Maximum fee limit is 10 percent");
        _liquidityFee = liquidityFee;
    }
   
    function setMaxTxPercent(uint256 maxTxPercent) external onlyOwner() {
        _maxTxAmount = _tTotal.mul(maxTxPercent).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
        emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }
    
     //to recieve ETH from pancakeRouter when swaping
    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Knowing that ethFees is at the moment equal to 157053209615704422268

I'd like to understand why the EVM is throwing that error at execution.
Also theres something weird happening when calling expectedRewards(), it throws an out of gas exception (on a call ???)

Comment: Please, can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: I just updated it

Comment: There are gas limits for each block and tx. If you loop through a big array that needs to use a lot of gas then you may exceed the limit which means the tx won't go through. It is best practice to never loop over big arrays.

Comment: But going deeply into the computation cost for every instruction, would excluding a huge part of the holders reduce the gas required to execute the function ? 

Above all, is there a way to calculate the eventual gas needed to run the transaction in order to compare it with the block gas limit ?